# NSFetchedResultsController NSRangeException after saving background context

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I can't reproduce this myself so all I have to go by are a few error logs I have collected. Can't really figure this one out. There are 2 FetchedResults controllers active when the crash happens. One on the main screen that displays how many items are in each category, and one to handle the category that you are drilled down into. All I know by the rest of the backtrace is that this issue always happens when inserting an object on the drilled down view. Any Ideas? Can someone at least confirm that the issue lies in updating the cell on the main screen and not inserting the cell on the detail screen?

Error:

** Please note that the interesting part seems to be that the range {0,3} and bounds [0 .. 1] is always the same in the 5-10 logs I have received on this issue **

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception \'NSRangeException\', reason: \'*** -[NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]: range {0, 3} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 1]\'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x35ad988f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x336fd259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35acda09 -[NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:] + 205
3   CoreData                            0x32e8e73d -[_NSDefaultSectionInfo indexOfObject:] + 133
4   CoreData                            0x32e8f299 -[NSFetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:] + 149
5   CoreData                            0x32e956f5 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 4361

Creating the Controller:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:mainContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:self.groupID];
```

NSFetchedResultsController Code:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
```

Configuring the cell:

```
-(void)configureCell:(MessageRow *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MymanagedObject *myobj = [self.convoController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.title = myobj.title
 }
```

Note that on my main screen everything is done basically the same way except for on an update the tableview row is reloaded instead of configured

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

The trick is to keep track of what is onscreen and what is offscreen. I check for those conditions in the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` callbacks and do not do any updates if the FRC is referring to offscreen data.

You can "catch up" with the updates later by using a trigger in `viewWillAppear` for example.

Comment: So you think the best solution is to stop being the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate on viewWillDissapear and turn it back on / refresh on viewWillAppear? How do you suggest catching up? [tableView refreshData]?

Comment: I tried that too, but it is less reliable. Somehow setting and unsetting the delegate does not always work if the delegate is not active on the main thread.

Comment: Just to be clear, in my situation there are two Controllers and 2 separate delegates. The detail controller fetches objects that are from a relationship of the main controller. Whenever I do an add, it increments a counter on the parent object thus triggering the delegate on the main controller as well. So it is not he same object being updated twice